# Setting up my models with has_many through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have become a little unstuck trying to setup my models with the correct associations, I have 3 models as follows

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
end

class ImageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Holds image_id and category_id to allow multiple categories to be saved per image, as opposed to storing an array of objects in one DB column
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :category
end
```

The `ImageCategory` table is my join table as I see it which holds all my `image_ids` with their corresponding `category_ids`, as a `Image` can have multiple `Categories`

Form to create Image

```
permit_params :id, :title, :description, :photo,
            category_ids: []
form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  inputs do
    f.semantic_errors
    f.input :title
    f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, cols: 10 }
    f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes
  end
end
```

When I try and then create an `image`, I get the following error:

```
can't write unknown attribute `image_id`
```

What error(s) have I made here?

Comment: can you please tell that on which object(image or image_category) you are binding the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way that you have set up your associations is causing you this issue.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
end

class ImageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :category
end
```

What your current associations describe is that a category can have many images through image_categories but image and image_categories are associated via category in your model which is not what I think you intend.

Comment: That has solved it, many thanks..just trying to get my head around how that works

Comment: A link table should connect two tables together. In order to link the two tables, images and categories to each other they both need to reference this link table. Think of this link table as something that sits in the middle, between these two tables. Both images table and categories table must have many links and therefore many link table associations, but each link can only be matched to one image, and one category.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, there is a mistake in Image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, through: :image_categories
  has_many :image_categories
end
```

Hope this  help you !!!

Comment: thanks, so i have made the change as you described, but i get `undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass` after submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Just to add there was no need for your join model `ImageCategory` in this case. Check out `has_and_belongs_to_many` association (HABTM).

`has_many:through` is useful in scenarios where you would need to add additonal attributes to your `ImageCategory` model other than `ImageId` and `CategoryId`.

In your scenario, however, `HABTM` will suffice.